# regex -- grepping for alphabetic characters only

Tags: regex

I have a quick regex question.

Let's say I have a list of packages:

```
packageA-0:8.39-6.fc24.x86_64 
packageB-0:6.4-1.fc24.x86_64
packageB-utils-0:3.63-2.fc24.x86_64
```

What I want returned is:

```
packageA
packageB
packageB-utils
```

I've tried

```
grep -oP '^[a-z]*' myfile.txt
```

and

```
awk -F"[_-]" '{print $1}' myfile.txt
```

Any ideas? I think I'm sort of close, but I just can't get `packageB-utils`

Comment: Um. Because `-` is not in `[a-z]*`, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
.*?(?=-\d)
```

- .*? => everything non greedy
- (?=-\d) => until "-" followed by a digit

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Selects everything upto the last alphabet:

```
grep -o "^[a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]" file.txt
```

Or, if your package name also contains digits, you can use `sed` to trim out everything after `-0:...`:

```
sed 's|-[0-9]*:.*||' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` using grouping:

```
sed -rn 's/([A-Za-z\-]+)\-(.*)/\1/p' packages.txt
```

Should yield:

```
#packageA
#packageB
#packageB-utils
```

`packages.txt` contains:

```
packageA-0:8.39-6.fc24.x86_64 
packageB-0:6.4-1.fc24.x86_64
packageB-utils-0:3.63-2.fc24.x86_64
```